# The button handler function setOnClickListener () is not showing toast after binding the data.Please let me know why it is not working?

Tags: android

I am making a layout which includes buttons on imageview.I am doing this in kotlin.I binded the data and now want to perform `setOnClickListener` on the button.So I just passed toast in that just to check whether it is working or not.It is not showing toast.

I have tried :

```java
   binding.decrease1.setOnClickListener { v: View? ->

          Toast.makeText(this.context,"bla",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

      }
```

decrease1 is buttonid

```java
class RemoteFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentRemoteBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel: RemoteViewModel
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_remote,container,false)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(RemoteViewModel::class.java)
        return binding.root

      binding.decrease1.setOnClickListener { v: View? ->

          Toast.makeText(this.context,"bla",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

      }
    }
}
```

Its not showing any error but not giving any output also

Comment: set it before return statement or inside `onViewCreated` fun

Comment: If you find my answer is helpful then please vote for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are setting listeners in unreachable code zone

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_remote,container,false)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(RemoteViewModel::class.java)


  binding.decrease1.setOnClickListener { v: View? ->

      Toast.makeText(this.context,"bla",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

  }

 return binding.root

}
```

Now it should work fine.

**NOTE**

After the last return, nothing will be called in general

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this-:

```
class RemoteFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentRemoteBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel: RemoteViewModel
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_remote,container,false)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(RemoteViewModel::class.java)
        return binding.root

      binding.decrease1.setOnClickListener { v: View? ->

          Toast.makeText(this.context,"bla",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

      }
    }
}
```

Do this-:

```
class RemoteFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentRemoteBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel: RemoteViewModel
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_remote,container,false)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(RemoteViewModel::class.java)

binding.decrease1.setOnClickListener { v: View? ->

          Toast.makeText(this.context,"bla",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

      }
    }

        return binding.root


}
```

You have to do that part of code before return binding.root